# Böhm-Jacopini theorem

Tags: algorithms, turing-machines

I had a discussion with a friend developer and teacher. He told me about the Structured program theorem arguing that this theorem is one of the most important to know about. However, I have never heard about it and I don't understand how it may have deeply contributed to the computer theory. It seems quite cited in academic papers though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had never heard about it before, but taking a quick look at it I can understand why it is considered so important.

Basically, being able to prove that any program can be implemented via three basic operations (sequence, seletion, iteration) allows for simpler formalization when designing a new programming language.

It's basically a one-to-one correspondance to a Turing machine programme, therefore you can easily prove your programming language to be Turing complete.

Comment: "It's basically a one-to-one correspondence to a Turing machine programme". What is this one-to-one correspondence? I cannot see where you defined it. How is it one-to-one?

Comment: Processing sequences, selections, and iterating on the tape are key features of the Turing machine, therefore if you're able to define everything in terms of such operations, you're also able to write a Turing machine programme which has the very same behaviour

Comment: "Processing sequences, selections, and iterating on the tape are key features of the Turing machine". Can you add a reference to this statement?

Comment: The (key) components of a Turing machine should be unbounded memory, finite states and a head as well as transition rules. The (key) ability of a Turing machine is its ability to update its state, the current cell and header location together bases on its current state and location.

Comment: What do you mean by "processing sequences" and "iterating" as features of the Turing machines? **What is the difference between the two as features of the Turing machines?**